# How to make an advanced search with Spring Data REST?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-data-rest

My task is to make an advanced search with Spring Data REST.
How can I implement it?

I managed to make a method to do a simple search, like this one:

```
public interface ExampleRepository extends CrudRepository<Example, UUID>{

    @RestResource(path="searchByName", rel="searchByName")
    Example findByExampleName(@Param("example") String exampleName);

}
```

This example works perfectly if I have to go simply to the url:

```
.../api/examples/search/searchByName?example=myExample
```

But what I have to do if there are more than one field to search?

For example, if my Example class has 5 fields, what implementation should I have to make an advanced search with all possibiles fileds?

Consider this one:

```
.../api/examples/search/searchByName?filed1=value1&field2=value2&field4=value4
```

and this one:

```
.../api/examples/search/searchByName?filed1=value1&field3=value3
```

What I have to do to implement this search in appropriate way?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look here https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: Found any better way, than the one you started with ?

Comment: Take a look to my answer.

Comment: I believe I accomplished what you're looking for, please check my answer.

Answer (score 15):

Spring Data Rest has integrated QueryDSL with web support as well which you can use for your advanced search requirement. You need to change your repository to implement `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` and things will work out of the box.

Here is a sample from the [blog](https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/04/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-gosling#querydsl-support) article about the feature:

```
$ http :8080/api/stores?address.city=York    
{
    "_embedded": {
        "stores": [
            {
                "_links": {
                    …
                }, 
                "address": {
                    "city": "New York", 
                    "location": { "x": -73.938421, "y": 40.851 }, 
                    "street": "803 W 181st St", 
                    "zip": "10033-4516"
                }, 
                "name": "Washington Hgts/181st St"
            }, 
            {
                "_links": {
                    …
                }, 
                "address": {
                    "city": "New York", 
                    "location": { "x": -73.939822, "y": 40.84135 }, 
                    "street": "4001 Broadway", 
                    "zip": "10032-1508"
                }, 
                "name": "168th & Broadway"
            }, 
            …
        ]
    }, 
    "_links": {
        …
    }, 
    "page": {
        "number": 0, 
        "size": 20, 
        "totalElements": 209, 
        "totalPages": 11
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I managed to implement this using [Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example).

Let's say you have the following models:

```
@Entity
public class Company {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  Long id;

  String name;
  String address;

  @ManyToOne
  Department department;

}


@Entity
public class Department {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  Long id;

  String name;

}
```

And the repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {
}
```

(Note that [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) implements [QueryByExampleExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor.html?is-external=true)).

Now you implement a custom controller:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CompanyCustomController {

  private final CompanyRepository repository;

  @GetMapping("/companies/filter")
  public ResponseEntity<?> filter(
      Company company,
      Pageable page,
      PagedResourcesAssembler assembler,
      PersistentEntityResourceAssembler entityAssembler
  ){

    ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
        .withIgnoreCase()
        .withStringMatcher(ExampleMatcher.StringMatcher.CONTAINING);

    Example example = Example.of(company, matcher);

    Page<?> result = this.repository.findAll(example, page);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(assembler.toResource(result, entityAssembler));

  }
}
```

And then you can make queries like:

```
localhost:8080/companies/filter?name=google&address=NY
```

You can even query nested entities like:

```
localhost:8080/companies/filter?name=google&department.name=finances
```

I omitted some details for brevity, but I created a [working example](https://github.com/jefferson-lima/sdr-filter-example/tree/master) on Github.

Answer (score 7):

The implementation of query methods is widely documented in [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.search-resource) and tons of technical blogs, though quite a bunch are outdated.

Since your question is probably "How can I perform a multi-parameter search with any combination of fields without declaring an awful lot of findBy* methods?", the answer is [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/), which is supported by [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe).

Comment: Don't think query dsl can be combined with SDR.

Comment: @matr0s take a look at the [QueryDslPredicateExecutor interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QueryDslPredicateExecutor.html). [Querydsl support in Spring](https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/04/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-gosling#querydsl-support) has been out since the Gosling release of Spring. I for one have been using it for months, I can humbly vouch for it ;)

Comment: Never knew query dsl has been integrated to SDR. Thank a lot for this link.

Answer (score 6):

I have found a working solution for this task.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection=MyProjection.class)
public interface MyRepository extends Repository<Entity, UUID> {

    @Query("select e from Entity e "
          + "where (:field1='' or e.field1=:field1) "
          + "and (:field2='' or e.field2=:field2) "
          // ...
          + "and (:fieldN='' or e.fieldN=:fieldN)"
    Page<Entity> advancedSearch(@Param("field1") String field1,
                               @Param("field2") String field2,
                               @Param("fieldN") String fieldN,
                               Pageable page);

}
```

With this solution, using this base url:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/examples/search/advancedSearch
```

We can make advanced searches with all the fields that we need.

Some examples:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/examples/search/advancedSearch?field1=example
    // filters only for the field1 valorized to "example"

http://localhost:8080/api/examples/search/advancedSearch?field1=name&field2=surname
    // filters for all records with field1 valorized to "name" and with field2 valorized to "surname"
```

Comment: Got a compilation error and modified as below.     @Query("select e from Entity e "
            +"where (:field1='' or e.field1=:field1) "
            +"and (:field2='' or e.field2=:field2) "
            //...
            +"and (:fieldN='' or e.fieldN=:fieldN) ")
    Page<Entity> advancedSearch(@Param("field1") String field1,
                                 @Param("field2") String field2,
                                 @Param("fieldN") String fieldN,
                                 Pageable page);

Answer (score 2):

I guess You can try following:

`List<Person> findDistinctPeopleByLastnameOrFirstname(@Param("lastName")String lastname, @Param("firstName")String firstname);`

and `examples/search/searchByLastnameOrFirstname?firstName=value1&lastName=value2`

Check out: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Yup, that is one of the link I pointed to in my earlier answer. Up to two parameters, this is OK, but with three or more, It becomes a bit awkward to define all the findBy methods. If your search fields are "A", "B" and "C", you quickly end up with : findByA, findByB, findByC, findByAAndBAndC, findByAAndB, findByAAndC, findByBAndC... now imagine A, B, C to be meaningful variable names, such as "name, description, createDate".

Comment: for now I'm trying something like this: personRepo.findAll(new PersonAdvancedSearch(name, surname, age, etc...)), where PersonAdvancedSearch implements Specification<Person>.
PersonAdvancedSearch overrides the method toPredicate. It seems to work, but i still have problems if the attribute is a complex type.

Comment: @AlessandroC maybe crafting your method manually with the [@Query](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) annotation could help you better handle search on your domain object.

Comment: well even if it where like this. 
your resource and repository are in one class. you dont need to write a single line of sql, besides defining a method in a repository interface and ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CriteriaOperator** to create advanced search with Spring Data.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.apulbere</groupId>
    <artifactId>crop</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For example you have a pet shop and want to search pets by name, birthdate, type etc. using different operators: like, equal, between etc.

The REST endpoint will look like:

```
http://localhost:64503/pets?birthdate.gte=2010-01-11&nickname.like=Ba
```

Where the query params have the following format: `fieldName.operatorName=value`

In controller you map your search criteria with the entity metamodel:

```
@GetMapping("/pets")
List<PetRecord> search(PetSearchCriteria petSearchCriteria) {
    return cropService.create(Pet.class, petSearchCriteria)
            .match(PetSearchCriteria::getNickname, Pet_.name)
            .match(PetSearchCriteria::getBirthdate, Pet_.birthdate)
            .getResultList()
            .stream()
            .map(petMapper::map)
            .toList();
}
```

Where the `PetSearchCriteria` is a simple DTO defined by you using data types form the library:

```
public class PetSearchCriteria {
    private StringCriteriaOperator nickname;
    private LocalDateCriteriaOperator birthdate;
}
```

Check out the [repository](https://github.com/apulbere/crop) for full example.