# Spring data rest order by nested path with querydsl

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I want to `order` using `Nested Path`

**Not working**

```
curl -i -X GET  http://localhost:8080/api/appointment?sort=doctor.name,{desc|asc} // Not working
```

**While this working**

```
curl -i -X GET  http://localhost:8080/api/appointment?sort=appointmentDay,{desc/asc} // working

curl -i -X GET  http://localhost:8080/api/appointment?dcotor.name=Ahmed // working
```

**Entity**

```
public class Appointment implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "appointment_day")
    @Future(message = "Day of appointment must be in the future!")
    @NotNull
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = Constants.DATE_PATTEN)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
    private Date appointmentDay;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id", nullable = false)
    private Doctor doctor;
    // Other properties 
    //
}
```

**Repository**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "appointment", collectionResourceRel = "data", excerptProjection = AppointmentExcerpt.class)
public interface AppointmentRepo extends JpaRepository<Appointment, Long>, 
QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Appointment>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QAppointment> {}
```

**Update**
[paging-and-sorting.adoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/paging-and-sorting.adoc)

> Sorting by linkable associations (i.e. resources to top-level
>   resources) is not supported.

**But** i see that was fixed [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-976?jql=text%20~%20%22sort%20nested%22%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC)

**Update** Added [3.0.0.M2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.0.0.M3/changelog.txt) which reported that issue fixed, But still **Not working**

> Changes in version [3.0.0.M2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.0.0.M3/changelog.txt) (2017-04-04)
>
> - DATAREST-976 - Sorting by an embedded property no longer works in Ingalls RC1.

```
<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>rabbit-milestones</id>
        <name>Rabbit Milestones</name>
        <url>https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/maven-milestones</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.M3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just **downgraded** `spring.data.‌​rest.webmvc` to `Hopper` release

```
<spring.data.jpa.version>1.10.10.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
<spring.data.rest.webmvc.version>2.5.10.RELEASE</spring.data.rest.webmvc.version>

/api/appointment?sort=doctor.name,{desc|asc} // works with (.)
/api/appointment?sort=doctor_name,{desc|asc} // works too  with (_)
```

Thanks [@Alan Hay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356423/alan-hay) comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42262846/1283715)

> Ordering by nested properties works fine for me in the Hopper release but I did experience the following bug in an RC version of the Ingalls release.bug in an RC version of the Ingalls release. This is reported as being fixed,

- [jira issue - Sorting by an embedded property no longer works in Ingalls RC1](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-976?jql=text%20~%20%22sort%20nested%22%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC)

**BTW**, I tried [`v3.0.0.M3`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.0.0.M3/changelog.txt)  that reported that fixed but not working with me.