# How to pass variable number of parameters to Spring Data/Hibernate/JPQL query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I need to pass in a variable number of parameters to a spring/JPA repo to mimick something like this.

```
select * from myTable 
where name like '%SOME_VALUE%'
or name like '%SOME_OTHER_VALUE%'
or name like '%SOME_OTHER_VALUE2%'
or an unknown number of other values
```

So far I haven't been able to determine what the correct way to to do this is. I'm using Spring 4.3.7, Hibernate 5.2.9, and Spring Data 1.11.1. I've googled around and it doesn't appear that there's way to do this with a normal CRUD repo, but so far I haven't found any examples that look like what I need. I think `CriteriaBuilder` is what I am supposed to use, but that seems to have fallen out of favor, so I'm not sure what the correct way to do this is.

Comment: Wouldn't it be just add a `List<YourTableEntity> find(String param1, String param2....)` method with an annotation like `@Query("SELECT y FROM YourTableEntity y WHERE y.name like '%:param1%' or like y.name like '%:param2%' ....` be sufficient?

Comment: If the number of parameters are unknown I would use [Specification<>](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)

Comment: You can just use JPQL like `SELECT  * FROM Table t WHERE t.col1 LIKE %?1% OR t.col2 LIKE %?2%  OR t.col3 LIKE %?3%`

Answer (score 1):

So I followed @Jorge Campos advice and used specification. My code looks like this now:

```
    public Stream<Product> findProductsContainingDesc(Collection<String> withDesc) {
        Specifications<Product> specifications = null;
        for (String s : withDesc) {
            if(specifications == null){
                specifications = where(hasDescriptionLike(s));
            }else{
                specifications = specifications.or(hasDescriptionLike(s));
            }
        }
        return internalProductRepository.findAll(specifications).stream();
    }

    public static Specification<Product> hasDescriptionLike(String desc) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> builder.like(root.get("description"), "%" + desc + "%");
    }
```

And my repo definition is this.

```
interface InternalProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this?:

```
@Query("select e from Entity e "
      +"where (:field1 = '' or e.field1 like '%:field1%') "
      +"and (:field2 = '' or e.field2 like '%:field2%') "
      //...
      +"and (:fieldN = '' or e.fieldN like '%:fieldN%')"
Page<Entity> advancedSearch(@Param("field1") String field1,
                           @Param("field2") String field2,
                           //...
                           @Param("fieldN") String fieldN,
                           Pageable page);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38652548/5380322).