# How to use CrudRepository with variations of parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to show a table of persons. The user should be able to send queries and filter by attributes that are mostly optional.

Problem: for each attribute to filter, I'd have to introduce a additional method in `spring-data-jpa` using `CrudRepository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findByFirstname(firstname);
    List<Person> findbyFirstnameAndLastname(first, last);
    List<Person> findByFirstnameAndLastnameAndAge(first, last, age);
    List<Person> findByFirstnameAndLastnameAndAgeAndCity(first, last, age, city);
}
```

Question: how could I do better (without having to write native
`PreparedStatement`s myself)?

Comment: This can help https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: As a variant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43229441

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Query by example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) allows creating filters by populating simple filter criterias into an "example" entity:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    <S extends T> Iterable<S> findAll(Example<S> example);
}

...

Person person = new Person();
person.setFirstname("Dave");
person.setCity("Seattle");
Iterable<Person> davesFromSeattle = personRepository.findAll(Example.of(person));
```

Comment: Well but how would you then create queries like "byFirstnameIgnoreCase", or "byAgeGreaterThan"?

Comment: For `ignored-case`, `like`, `starts-with`, `ends-with` you can use *ExampleMather*. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.execution

Comment: For numeric ranges, you can try more complex (but more powerful) `Specification` approach. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

Answer (score 0):

you use pagination and stream queries for batter result set requirement entity

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set your required properties on entity and pass it to method `findAll (Entity entity)`

For example if you want employees with some property value then set that parameters on it and pass is to query database.

```
Employee employee = new Employee ();
employee. setAge (35);
employee. setExperience(5);
```

Now pass it for query

```
List <Employee> employèes = do. findAll (Employee);
```

Comment: Does this really work? Searching by an `@Entity` bean?