# Add method to all Spring Data Rest controllers

Tags: spring-data-rest

I implemented a filter for Spring Data Rest using Query by Example in a custom controller, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54517551/2752969).

I would like all my entities to have this filter. How can I extend Spring Data Rest with a generic implementation of this filter?

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply use the QueryDsl support that you get out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

Add @RequestMapping(value = "/{repository}/filter", method = RequestMethod.GET) to the controller.

Add `@QuerydslPredicate RootResourceInformation resourceInformation` and `Map<String,String> map` arguments to thee controller. The resoureceInformation will contain the typeInfo of the actual entity type (Spring Data Rest finds the appropriate entity by the `repository` pathvariable)

If you have the typeInfo and all the property name-values, then you can recreate the proper type of `example`.

--------------- Edit

I'm working on an extension for Spring Data Rest. Basically it's an access-control extension, but it has an inbuilt search function too. (Even more flexible than this general filter) However, switching to this package only because of the search feature would be a bit overkill. But if can find some other useful features you should consider giving it a try. [ACL-search](https://github.com/BerryCloud/spring-data-jpa-acl/tree/master/acl#aclsearchable)